# Visio 2010 - How to show page number for Off-page reference shape?

Tags: visio

I‘m making logic-diagrams in Visio 2010 and are using Off-page reference to link between pages. But I would like to show on the Off-page reference shape the page number which is reference to. That means that if there is reference from page 1 to page 3 I would like Visio to automatically show “page 3” on the shape at page 1 and vise-verse. Is there anyone that have a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can try clicking on the off page reference shape once (just so that it's selected, if you double click it'll take you to the off page reference) and just start typing "Page 1". It doesn't look like it's selected and ready for you to the type b/c just the border is selected but it'll work.